# What's the height of a UITabBar on iOS 8, iOS 9, iOS 10, and iOS 11?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uitabbar, ios9

The height of the UITabBar seems to have changed between iOS 7 and 8/9/10/11. I'm posting this question for others to easily find the answer.

So: What's the height of a UITabBar on iOS 8/9/10/11 on iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

For iOS 8, 9, and 10 the height is **49 points**, both on iPad and iPhone and both in portrait and landscape. It used to be 56 points on iOS 7.

For iOS 11, things get a bit more complicated:

In **portrait** and **regular landscape**, the height is still **49 points**.
In **compact landscape**, the height is now **32 points**.

On iPhone X, the height is **83 points** in portrait and **53 points** in landscape.

Comment: Thanks Johannes :)

Comment: Actually, the height is still 49 points on iPhone X- the 34 points below it are the space below the safe area.

Comment: for the new iPhone Xs (iPhone XS, XS Max, XR) the height is 83 points in portrait and 70 points in landscape.

Comment: (tabBar.frame.size.height - (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 34)) works on all devices

Answer (score 21):

iOS 9 and iOS 10 still uses 49 points for the Tab Bar (and 64 points for a navigation bar)
Thanks for the self Q/A, was actually helpful to conform what I had on storyboard.

Comment: Good for consistence.

Comment: as a note of further update, ios 10 has the same heights for tab bar and navigation bar (49 points for tab bar, 64 points for navigation bar).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend just calculating it using `TabBar.Height - UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.SafeAreaInsets.Bottom`. Check for system version >= 11 first.

Comment: (tabBar.frame.size.height - (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 34))

Answer (score 3):

| iPhone | portrait | landscape |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5s/SE/6/6s/7/8(iOS10) | 49 | 49 |
| 5s/SE/6/6s/7/8(iOS11) | 49 | 32 |
| X/XS/XR | 83(49+34) | 53(32+21) |
| XS Max | 83(49+34) | 70(49+21) |

you can get by this method:
`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height`