# iOS 8 iPad tab bar height is different than iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios8, tabbar

Does any one know if the official documentation tells us the height of the tab bar on iOS 8 iPad applications?

My app's tab bar frame is (0, 719) (1024, 49) on my landscape iPad app on iOS 8.
For iOS 7, it's (0, 712), (1024, 56).

I read in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html that the height on iOS 7 ipads is 56 pixels. I'm guessing it's not the same for iOS 8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550831/whats-the-height-of-a-uitabbar-on-ios-8

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Apple have changed the iPad tab bar height back to 49pt in iOS 8. [An Apple engineer has confirmed the change.](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1012545#1012545) The documentation seems to have not updated however.

So for iPad, the UITabBar heights per iOS version are:

- iOS 6 and earlier - 49pt
- iOS 7 - 56pt
- iOS 8 and later - 49pt

The tab bar has always been 49pt on iPhone and remains that way.

Comment: it should be  **Pt** Not **px**---> **49pt**

Answer (score 2):

You can get the size of the tab bar programmatically instead

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.bounds.size
```