# self.tabBarController sometimes nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have `UIViewController` (*first*) which has tab bar at the bottom. I have next code in this controller:

```
let tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
```

It's working fine, but when I'm going from this *first* to next one (*second*) controller and then pressing `Back` button and returning to *first*, `self.tabBarController` is nil. Why does it happen? I have only one version, that stack of controllers is overcrowded.

How can I fix this? I need this height to calculate some value for constraint change in `keyboardWillShow` function.

**UPDATE:**

How do I call it:

```
// MARK: - Scroll view on keyboard show/hide
extension CommentariesController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
           let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
           let tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
               self.newCommentViewBotConstraint.constant = -keyboardHeight + tabBarHeight!
               self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
           })
        }
    }

    // other code 
}
```

**Update 2:**

I can see `tab bar`. But it is `nil`.

Structure (with `Show` segues): `tabbar -> navbar -> viewcontroller -> viewcontroller -> viewcontroller (first) -> viewcontroller (second)`.

Thanks

Comment: is it only happening sometimes?? Where `tabBarController` in nil in 'viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` ??

Comment: @Bilal only in situation, that I have described. Here: extension CommentariesController: UITextFieldDelegate {
   func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

Comment: Have you tried calling it inside `keyboardWillShow`? That should be fine. If you try calling `self.tabBarController` before the ViewController is on the screen, it might return nil, which I think is your case here.

Comment: @TawaNicolas I always call it in keyboadWillShow :)

Comment: How are you going to the next view controller, are you pushing it.

Comment: @AravindAR i use "show"

Comment: Ok then which viewcontroller is set as the root of your window??

Comment: @AravindAR tab bar controller. Structure : tabbar -> navbar -> viewcontroller -> viewcontroller -> viewcontroller (first) -> viewcontroller (second). Like this. I can see tab bar btw. Was a mistake in last comment

Comment: Ok thanks, I am trying on a demo project will let you know if I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @AravindAR thanks you for your time

Comment: Between how are you adding notification observer to CommentariesController ?

Comment: Most likely this happens when the controller has hidden, which causes the keyboard to disappear and it also causes the tab bar to be `nil`.

Comment: @Sulthan what do u mean? I come back to this controller. And in this controller I'm trying to get height. And I can see tab bar. Can u explain it again? Thanks you!

Comment: @AravindAR like always: NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CommentariesController.keyboardWillShow),
                                             name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CommentariesController.keyboardWillHide),
                                             name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

Comment: Ok. I tried out the above code on a sample project but I'm not getting self.tabBarController as nil. I'm sorry but I couldn't find anything that lead to this issue.

Comment: @AravindAR can you please add answer with screenshot of the storybord?:)

Comment: @VladPulichev done

Answer (score 1):

[image]

TabBar controller is set as the root and then navigation controller as tabBar's one of the item and the TestViewController as the root of that navigation controller. Then this TestViewController has a textfield to check the keyboardWillShow function and on tapping the UIButton - "button" new viewcontroller is pushed. On tapping back and again checking `keyboardWillShow` function `self.tabBarController` is not nil and I'm getting the correct height of tabBar inside that function

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TestViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)


    extension TestViewController {
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
            let tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                print("tabBarheight - \(tabBarHeight)")

            })
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I will uparrow for your pain. But I have more viewcontrollers. And I think here is a problem:(

Comment: Ok thanks man. I will look into it when you upload the screenshot of your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS >= 8.0, the tabbar height is always 49 pt (see [What's the height of a UITabBar on iOS 8, iOS 9 and iOS 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550831/whats-the-height-of-a-uitabbar-on-ios-8-ios-9-and-ios-10)).

If you need some complex UI use case to solve when the tabbar is not accessible, just put that number into a constant and use that, e.g.:

```
let tabbarHeight: CGFloat = 49.0
```

or, save the value to a variable, e.g.

```
var tabbarHeight:

viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)

    self.tabbarHeight = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height
}
```

Comment: On Ipad it also would be 49?

Comment: And main question why is it happening and how to fix it. Anyway thanks for answer and your time

Comment: @VladPulichev This is happening because your controller is not in any tabbar controller which is normal during transitions. The exact reason depends on your controller hierarchy and how you are handling the keyboard.

Comment: I still can't understand why it is in tab bar and after show another and back to this it is not in:(

Comment: I can add screenshot in the evening. Of storyboard